# Instance variable showing up as `nil` in rspec

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

I have the following test code:

```
require_relative '../spec_helper'

describe Chess::King do
  before do
    @piece = Chess::King.new('king1',:black)
    @board = Chess::Board.new
  end

  describe '#possible_moves' do
    context "placing king at location 4,5" do
      @board.grid[4][5] = @piece
      subject {@piece.possible_moves(@board)}
      it {is_expected.to eq([3,5],[3,6],[4,6],[5,6],[5,5])}
    end
  end
end
```

Why am I getting this error:

> in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined method`grid' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

I am not sure about this line: `@board.grid[4][5] = @piece`.

My intention here is to assign the piece object to the grid instance variable of board (8x8 array).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [`let`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-5/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let) instead:

```
require_relative '../spec_helper'

describe Chess::King do
  let(:piece) { Chess::King.new('king1',:black) }
  let(:board) { Chess::Board.new }

  describe '#possible_moves' do
    context "placing king at location 4,5" do
      before(:each) { board.grid[4][5] = piece }
      subject {piece.possible_moves(board)}
      it {is_expected.to eq([3,5],[3,6],[4,6],[5,6],[5,5])}
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:667:in `method_missing': `board` is not available on an example group (e.g. a `describe` or `context` block). It is only available from within individual examples (e.g. `it` blocks) or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. `before`, `let`, etc). (RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::WrongScopeError)

Comment: I think you were misusing the [`context`](http://lmws.net/describe-vs-context-in-rspec) block - see my edit

Comment: Everything is good, however @piece in the before block is nil. It does not refer to anything. So my test doesn't work still.

Comment: Good Ill remove my answer then.